# How to sync to remote server with phonegap CouchDB Lite (CBLite) plugin?

Tags: couchdb, phonegap-plugins

I use the phonegap CouchDB Lite in my Javascript Mobile App with the phonegap plugin "com.couchbase.lite.phonegap".

I get all my data saved in the local DB but I could find the way to sync this local database to an other instance CouchDB database such as iriscouch.com.

The only method that seems available is:

```
window.cblite.getURL(function (err, url){})
```

I would expect something like cblite.sync(db, url_remote) or something like that...

Comment: read about the sync gateway http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/get-started/what-is-sync-gateway/index.html  https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchChat-PhoneGap

Comment: Thanks Gaetano, there is a Chat Example which uses sync: https://github.com/couchbaselabs/CouchChat-PhoneGap